# mysql start date and end date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have been trying to get particular dates from date and end date
eg 01-01-2016 to 12-31-2016 dates only. But iam getting 2015 date only
this is my query

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT date FROM `table` WHERE date between '1/1/2016' and '12/29/2016'");
       echo $this->db->last_query(); exit;
    if ($query == true) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $t) {
            echo $t->date . '<br>';
        }
    } else { return false; }
```

but im getting 2015 records

Comment: change date fomat yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: `varchar` is different from `date`.

Comment: @vishal would you please tell us in which format the dates are stored in your db ? try to compare with that format

Comment: like this in the table 8/18/2016

Comment: yes actually it is in date field it is in varchar instead of date format. Is anything i can do or i have to change to date type in db for date

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
between '1/1/2016' and '12/29/2016'");
```

mysql default date format is `'Y-m-d'`, so change your date to this format and try again i.e.

```
between '2016-1-1' and '2016-12-29'");
```

Comment: no results  SELECT date FROM `table` WHERE date between '2016/01/01' and '2016/12/30'

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT date FROM `table` WHERE DATE(date) between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-29'");
   echo $this->db->last_query(); exit;
if ($query == true) {
    foreach ($query->result() as $t) {
        echo $t->date . '<br>';
    }
} else { return false; }
```

Use your code like in **Y-m-d** formate .mysql accept this format

Comment: only this format ? are you sure ? can't be another format ?

Comment: I think "Y-m-d H:i:s" also there...depends on database column value

Comment: @ Rajat Gupta :D first confirm the things then tell to any one on SO otherwise you may get down votes

Comment: Y-m-d is the default date format. and mysql accept more format..I will keep in mind this thing ..Thanks for advice @Bunker Boy

Answer (score 0):

if your DB field is varchar then tyr this

```
SELECT date FROM `table` WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date,'%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-29'
```

Comment: i have written 0 results  SELECT AppointmentDate FROM `tables_name` WHERE STR_TO_DATE(AppointmentDate,'%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '1/01/2016' AND '12/14/2016'

Comment: its working in my system, do you have data between  '1/01/2016' AND '12/14/2016' ?

Comment: no only dates.The above code working for u.But im getting 0 results

Comment: Is there any data available in your database for AppointmentDate column between '1/01/2016' AND '12/14/2016' ?

Comment: i wrote this query working but im getting 2017 records also             SELECT AppointmentDate FROM `table_name` WHERE AppointmentDate >= '1/01/2016' AND AppointmentDate <='8/8/2016'

Comment: try this 
 SELECT AppointmentDate FROM table_name WHERE STR_TO_DATE(AppointmentDate,'%m/%d/%Y') >= '1/10/2016' AND STR_TO_DATE(AppointmentDate,'%m/%d/%Y') <='8/8/2016'

Comment: nop getiing 2017 records with 2016. Is anyting where i can stop 2017 records in the query

Comment: yes i got know i just reserves it  SELECT AppointmentDate FROM table_name WHERE STR_TO_DATE(AppointmentDate,'%m/%d/%Y')>='2016-01-01' and STR_TO_DATE(AppointmentDate,'%m/%d/%Y')<='2016-12-14'

Comment: thanks@Dilip Patel and all other for ur reply thanks

Comment: know for which i have to keep up-words / check

Answer (score 0):

if the date in varchar condition

SELECT AppointmentDate FROM table_name WHERE STR_TO_DATE(AppointmentDate,'%m/%d/%Y')>='2016-01-01' and STR_TO_DATE(AppointmentDate,'%m/%d/%Y')<='2016-12-14'